# Laravel Deploy Issue Shared Host

Tags: php, git, laravel, deployment

I am using hawkhost as my server
I successfully created a project and arrived to Laravel Page
Then I pushed the whole laravel respository with git, then I create a new folder in my server and git clone the respository. (respository no any change)
I cant access to Laravel Page, only the Error 500 shown

The reason I do this because I want to build the project in my local machine, then I push it and clone it in server. But I encounter having the same project One can access, another cant access

Comment: i do this all time but im using MS azure and it's get pulled automaticly which is nice. but shared hosting? why?

Answer (score 0):

please check log file and share here to get help, however

**Posibble Reason 1:**
.env file not available because of gitignore (APP_KEY is needed)

**Posibble Reason 2:** Storage folder is not writable

**Posibble Reason 3:** Could be server issue!